# django-social-auth incorrect authentication service

Tags: django, facebook, oauth, socialauth

I was trying to use django-social-auth today, but turned out I got an error everytime I tried to login using it.

I was using the example found in its git master branch, put in my facebook keys, but when I click to login using facebook, the error "Incorrect authentication service" appears.

That also occurs in twitter and orkut logins... does anyone have any idea why that may be happening?

Thanks a lot!

## Edit

Yeah, I'm sorry, I forgot to post my code.

#### settings.py

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, basename, join

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ROOT_PATH = abspath(dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_NAME = basename(ROOT_PATH)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test.db',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
MEDIA_URL = ''

SECRET_KEY = '****'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'social_auth',
    'app',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.yahoo.YahooBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.OpenIDBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.livejournal.LiveJournalBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

#### local_settings.py

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY              = ''
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET           = ''
FACEBOOK_APP_ID                   = '226521154024720'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET               = '9955be3b6e211b51921cb4b8eb08e69e'
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY             = ''
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET          = ''
ORKUT_CONSUMER_KEY                = ''
ORKUT_CONSUMER_SECRET             = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_KEY          = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET       = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS          = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_RANDOM_USERNAME = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME      = 'socialauth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME     = 'complete'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL                   = '/login/error/'
#SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL            = 'app.CustomUser'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ERROR_KEY             = 'socialauth_error'
```

The rest of the codes are exactly the same in example in github.com/omab/django-social-auth
if you need any other code, just tell me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without seeing your configuration this will simply be a shot in the dark. But the `django-social-auth` code has this:

```
def complete_process(request, backend):
    """Authentication complete process"""
    backend = get_backend(backend, request, request.path)
    if not backend:
        return HttpResponseServerError('Incorrect authentication service')
    ...
```

So, offhand, I would guess that you don't have the right backend configured or, at the very least, Django can't find it. Make sure you have the appropriate backend configured in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and that you've obtained the required OAuth keys from the service you want to use.

Keep in mind, too, that this error occurs in the `django-social-auth` code in a few places, but always when the specified backend can't be retrieved.

Comment: I edited my question, I think the appropriated backends are configured in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, aren't they? I looked into django-social-auth before asking it here, thought it would be what you just said, but, I couldn't see any errors in my config... Thanks!

Comment: Well, nevermind, it was a stupid mistake... The local_settings was named local_settings_template, but I didn't notice it at all. Sorry guys. I think I'm dislexic...

Comment: I don't think you're dyslexic -- I think simple things like this happen all the time when you're staring at code for awhile. Sometimes it helps just to have another pair of eyes! Happy coding.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was that I had FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET instead of FACEBOOK_API_SECRET. It was due to the fact that I migrated from django-facebook to django-social-auth.

Comment: Oh how I LOVE Stack Overflow for comments like this!

Comment: Did it help you? :) Did you do the same migration?

Answer (score 4):

It may be you don't have the FACEBOOK_APP_ID or FACEBOOK_API_SECRET set.