# twitter does not work in django socialauth

Tags: django, twitter, socialauth

I am using [django socialauth of OMAB](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), [I am using the example](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/tree/master/example) works next to the file have not changed anything, but I put it in local_settings.py:

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY              = 'Mk' this is no real
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET           = 'MTw' this is no real
FACEBOOK_APP_ID                   = ''
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET               = ''
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY             = ''
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET          = ''
ORKUT_CONSUMER_KEY                = ''
ORKUT_CONSUMER_SECRET             = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID           = ''
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET       = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS          = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_RANDOM_USERNAME = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME      = 'socialauth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME     = 'socialauth_complete'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL                   = '/login/error/'
#SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL            = 'app.CustomUser'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ERROR_KEY             = 'socialauth_error'
GITHUB_APP_ID                     = ''
GITHUB_API_SECRET                 = ''
FOURSQUARE_CONSUMER_KEY           = ''
FOURSQUARE_CONSUMER_SECRET        = ''
```

this is my settings.py

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, basename, join

try:
    import social_auth
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, "..")

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ROOT_PATH = abspath(dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_NAME = basename(ROOT_PATH)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test.db',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
MEDIA_URL = ''

SECRET_KEY = 't2eo^kd%k+-##ml3@_x__$j0(ps4p0q6eg*c4ttp9d2n(t!iol'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'social_auth',
    'app',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('google', 'google-oauth', 'facebook', 'twitter')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.yahoo.YahooBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.flickr.FlickrBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.OpenIDBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.livejournal.LiveJournalBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

try:
    from local_settings import *
except:
    pass
```

I have the same ***[problem as the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246970/django-social-auth-incorrect-authentication-service)*** tries to rename local_settings.py to local_settings_template.py and does not work and vice versa. This user does not know how to resolved this problem, do not know how to contact you to ask. if someone could test the sample to see if has the same problem would help me a lot.

Comment: I modified my question, and remember that I am using the example

Comment: Try not enabling the social_auth backends you are not using.

Comment: I do not understand, that I should put and remove

Comment: I removed  social_auth backends but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get twitter working with the following modifications

settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.google.TwitterBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('twitter',)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY              = 'xxx' 
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET           = 'yyy' 

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_auth',
)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
```

Of course this is needed:

```
% python manage.py syncdb
```

To test this directly with Twitter (without configuring any other pieces of your project/application), simply browse to /login/twitter and you should go through the authentication dance, your user will be added to the database and you'll be redirected (to a non-existent URL, but you'll have the user information).

From there you should be able to get it working with your system.

Comment: another question you worked in your localhost ? , or in the hosting that yout register in your twitter app